# Select TOP x records and return count

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I an using SQLServer 2008r2 and have this query:

```
SELECT top 18 id, obsDate,impact FROM diseaseHits WHERE diseaseID=2 AND pCode=3352 AND obsDate <= '2014/11/5 11:30:00 PM'
```

which returns:

```
1
1
0
1
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
```

Now all I want to do is  SUM these.  Impact is an int.  I just cant seem to get it working.   I cant do a SELECT TOP 20 COUNT.... so I tried this:

```
SELECT count(impact) FROM DiseaseHits where DiseaseHits.ID IN(SELECT top 20 id FROM diseaseHits WHERE diseaseID=2 AND pCode=3352 AND obsDate <= '2014/11/5 11:30:00 PM' ORDER by obsDate desc ) ;
```

but no luck.  How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: What is the expected result. I hope you should use `SUM` instead of `count`

Comment: Can you do something like this, I don't have SQL Server pulled up so hard to do: SELECT SUM(total) FROM (SELECT top 18 id+obsDate+impact AS total FROM diseaseHits WHERE diseaseID=2 AND pCode=3352 AND obsDate <= '2014/11/5 11:30:00 PM')

Comment: Yes I should have been using SUM thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use a subquery:

```
select sum(impact)
from (select top 18 id, obsDate, impact
      from diseaseHits
      where diseaseID = 2 AND pCode = 3352 AND obsDate <= '2014/11/5 11:30:00 PM'
     ) t;
```

I would also advise you to use a more standard date format, such as `'2014-11-05 11:30:00 PM'`.

Comment: Could probably just remove the id and obsDate as well since you don't need them in the result set.

Comment: Thank you.  that seems to do it.  Clearly I am just not thinking, of course I should be using SUM and not COUNT.  Thanks again, a nice day to you

Comment: What is the t for at the end?

Comment: @Mat41 the `t` at the end is an alias for the subquery, which is required, may be more familiar with seeing aliases assigned with `AS` like `AS t`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

Is this u want to do.

```
SELECT top 18 id, obsDate, impact, count(id) OVER() AS countOfid FROM diseaseHits WHERE diseaseID=2 AND pCode=3352 AND obsDate <= '2014/11/5 11:30:00 PM'
```